# OpenCV machine learning functions want CvFileStorage* instead of cv::FileStorage*

Tags: c++, opencv, machine-learning, computer-vision, neural-network

I am using the CvANN_MLP functions from the machine learning libraries in OpenCV, and I want to write my trained network to a file. I have been able to do this fine with cv::FileStorage for keypoints and descriptors when using SIFT, but when I try to do it here it does not work.

The header for the machine learning uses CvFileStorage throughout, but I cannot declare this object without getting a *"CvFileStorage fs has initializer but incomplete type"* error, and passing in a cv::FileStorage is no help at all.

I figured maybe this is because I don't have the most recent build of OpenCV, but I checked in the SVN repository, and it still has CvFileStorage in its prototypes.

Comment: the easiest way is to use `mlp.save(...)`

Comment: Post the answer in new post below please.

Answer (score 1):

*Solution written by [Will](https://stackoverflow.com/users/252053/will), originally posted as part of their question.*

Hidden in the `cv::FileStorage` class is the following:

```
// returns the underlying CvFileStorage*
CvFileStorage* operator *() { return fs; }
const CvFileStorage* operator *() const { return fs; }
```

Comment: Note to future editors: please do not remove attribution. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356951/if-i-repost-an-answer-merged-into-a-question-do-i-need-to-note-the-attribution